# Table cell is expanding when hover bold on cell content

Tags: html, css, asp.net, cell

I have a dynamically created asp:table on my website.  In one column of the table, I have an asp:Label in each row which is populated with usernames.  On the header row, the cell width for that column is set to 150px.  The max width of a username is around 75px.  On each label, I have a CSS hover class that changes the font color and makes the font BOLD.  When you hover over the longest usernames, all cells in that column expand, which pushes the other columns out a few pixels.  How do I fix this?

I am aware of declaring column groups for an HTML table, however, I can't do that with an asp:table control.

```
Table tbl = new Table();

TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();

TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.Attributes.Add("style", "width:50px");
cell1.Text = "Rank";
headerRow.Cells.Add(cell1);

TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell2.Attributes.Add("style", "width:150px");
cell2.Text = "User";
headerRow.Cells.Add(cell2);

TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
cell3.Attributes.Add("style", "width:75px");
cell3.Text = "Champion";
headerRow.Cells.Add(cell3);

tbl.Rows.Add(headerRow);

foreach (var user in users)
{
    TableRow contentRow = new TableRow();

    TableCell contentCell1 = new TableCell();
    contentCell1.Text = user.Rank.ToString();
    contentRow.Cells.Add(contentCell1);

    TableCell contentCell2 = new TableCell();
    Label userLbl = new Label();
    userLbl.Text = user.UserName;
    userLbl.CssClass = "HoverLabel";
    contentCell2.Controls.Add(Label);
    contentRow.Cells.Add(contentCell2);

    TableCell contentCell3 = new TableCell();
    contentCell3.Text = user.Champion.ToString();
    contentRow.Cells.Add(contentCell2);

    tbl.Rows.Add(contentRow);
}
```

Comment: Please add some code (All the relevant)..

Answer (score 1):

Making text bold will expand it, so first look at increasing `width` if it doesn't fit.

But if you insist on "cropping" text that doesn't fit you can force it with the following styles:

Table: `table-layout: fixed` and `width` value

TableCell:  `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;`